# Обновление проекта в Git

Tags: git

У меня на Git есть проект, нужно его обновить - полностью заменить файлы, git pull не подойдет в итоге так как объединяет коммиты, а в моем последнем коммите должна быть только новая информация. git push -f использовать нельзя. Может быть есть какой-нибудь аналог git push -f? Если есть - подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы хотите получить конечный результат аналогичный выполнению `git push -f`, не меняя истории, вам нужно создать наборы изменений, которые приведут к нужному конечному результату.

Проще всего для этого создать резервную копию рабочей директории(попросту скопировав файлы без папки .git).

Делаете `git checkout -f && git pull`, синхронизируя рабочую директорию с удалённой историей.
После этого просто удаляете всё, кроме папки .git, перемещаете файлы из резервной копии поверх(создаёте то, что должно быть и удаляете то, чего быть не должно) и одним коммитом приводите всё к нужному состоянию. `git push`

Comment: это решение тоже подошло. Спасибо большое

Comment: А что значит *`git push -f`, не меняя истории*?

Comment: Переписывание истории - это когда  зафиксированные наборы изменений заменяются другими

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо, но я не про это. Выделенное курсивом — оксюморон.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача "полностью заменить файлы на те, что находятся в удалённом репозитории", можете просто забить на локальную ветку:

```
git fetch origin master # подтянуть удалённую ветку (master - пример)
git checkout -f -b updated origin/master # переключиться на новую локальную ветку updated совпадающую с origin/master
```

Теперь Вы можете по желанию удалить локальную ветку master и создать её на новом месте)

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомненья) А не перепутал ли я что и где вы хотите обновить)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую
не перепутали)

Comment: может вопрос вам покажется глупым (я новичок): а как в новую ветку добавить только новые файлы, чтобы со старыми они не мерджелись?

Comment: Поясните мне, пожалуйста. Где у вас новые файлы? В локальной истории или в удалённой?

Comment: в локальном репозитории

Comment: Значит таки перепутал. Посмотрите на второй мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

если вы хотите, чтобы в последнем коммите было только добавление ваших новых файлов, то значит в предыдущем коммите должно быть удаление всех существующих. верно?

1. склонируйте хранилище
2. удалите все файлы:

   ```
   $ git rm -rf .
   ```
3. создайте коммит (это будет тот, что выше назван «предыдущим»)
4. скопируйте сюда ваши файлы (смотрите, чтобы каталог `.git` ни в коем случае не был затронут), добавьте их в индекс:

   ```
   $ git add .
   ```
5. создайте коммит (это будет тот, что выше назван «последним»).

всё, можете отправлять получившуюся кашу в общее хранилище.

Comment: спасибо большое, получилось)